# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" - here_sdk example error

Tags: flutter-dependencies

followed these instructions on Github to run a here_sdk example and received an error. Trying to run a Here example in Flutter for the first time and not having success with these instructions or other instructions found on Here developer documentation.

Link to Here Documentation - https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.3.1.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

**Get Started for Flutter**

Unzip the HERE SDK for Flutter plugin to the plugins folder that can be found inside the example app project. Rename the folder to 'here_sdk': hello_map/plugins/here_sdk **(Done)**

Set your HERE SDK credentials to
hello_map/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml **(Done)**
hello_map/ios/Runner/Info.plist **(Done)**

Start an Android emulator or an iOS simulator and execute flutter run from the app's directory - or run the app from within your IDE.**(Will not run due to errror)**

Link - https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples#get-started-for-flutter

Error Received:

event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, message: Running "flutter pub get" in hello_map_app...}
**Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\sec\Flutter\examples\Here Examples\hello_map_app\plugins\here_sdk".**
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\sec\Flutter\examples\Here Examples\hello_map_app\plugins\here_sdk".)

The error is correct, no yaml file was found in the here_sdk download for Flutter.

Comment: Having the same issue, good question